# Finding borderline of object detected by OpenCV Cascade Classifier

Tags: opencv, computer-vision, object-detection

I use OpenCV Cascade Classifier to detect certain objects on images. But it returns only coordinates of rectangle with target object. Is there any way to find an accurate borderline of the object?

Answer (score 0):

It turned out that this is called "Image Segmentation" and what openCV NN did was "Object Detection".
Useful link: https://missinglink.ai/guides/computer-vision/image-segmentation-deep-learning-methods-applications/